# How do I curve a model that has multiple parts?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, geometry

I am a beginner at Blender and was wondering how I would create good-looking curved roads for my game (in Roblox Studio). My previous attempts looked off and didn't give me the angles I wanted. Also, I'm sure manually moving everything is not what I'm supposed to do.

[image]

I wanted to make roads that go 90, 45, and 15 degrees. Here were my previous attempts:
[image]
^^ The corner looks weird and I didn't make it long enough to make the turn bigger.

[image]

^^ My attempts at trying to figure it out.

I also cannot find where to make vertices snap to each other because I remember that being possible. Also, the pivot points get all out of place for some reason and I cannot figure out how to correct it.

Comment: You could investigate Blender's Spin tool. Whie most tutorials show it being used on 3D objects, there's no reason why you can't just use it on a flat plane object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the last time I used Roblox Studio, I recall a pretty small polygon or vertice limit for meshes. Because of this, along with in-game performance reasons, it is often best to model 'by hand' (i.e. without a bunch of modifiers) in Blender when you have very unforgiving geometry limits, like the ones that Roblox Studio has present use with here. For all our purposes, that rules out geometry nodes, along with many of the other modifiers.
That being said, there are as always, still a variety of ways to approach this.

## Method One

We can create a circle and and then extrude the edges like so (shown here would be 15 degrees)
[image: adding circle]
note that I set the fill mode to triangle fan and that I set the vertex count to 360/15 (24), so this allows us to delete all but one face
[image: ss2]
You can go ahead and extrude the edge that lies along the y axis along global x if you wish, but that only works because that edge is perpendicular to X. so that only works for this case

instead, press `,` and change the transform orientation to 'Normal'
This part is important! When you extrude the edge, dont move it! Press 'E' then 'Esc' Now press 'G' 'Z' to move the newly created edge along the the normal, because *extruding* along the normal will also change the distance the vertices are from eachother, which we dont want.
[image]

## better method

The far easier method, in my opinion is to select the vertice you want to rotate around, and press `Shift`+`S` --> 'Cursor to Selected'
[image]
Then simply press `2` to switch to edge select mode, and press `.` --> '3D Cursor'
[image]
Now, press `E` followed by `Esc`, which is what we did in the last method to duplicate the edge. Now press `R` (hold `Ctrl` if you don't have snapping enabled prior to this operation) and rotate!
[image]

---

### Regardless of which method you use, don't forget to merge the extra vertices  made when you extruded `M` --> `B` 'By distance'

For most scenarios like this, I would use geometry nodes or at least an array and curve modifier, but this is not one of those cases, given our constraints.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply! For the second method, are you using any special keybinds that you changed? The keys don't seem to do the same thing that you told me and it won't rotate around the 3D cursor. I'm going to keep trying the method though.

Comment: Disregard what I said before, your method works! Thank you!